# ¿Cómo validar folios continuos con Laravel?

Tags: php7, laravel-8

Tengo una función en mi controlador de Laravel que permite la creación de folios automáticos, hasta el momento todo bien, selecciono una serie y me muestra el folio que sigue:

---

$serie = $request->serieAnterior;

```
    $folio = folio::join('serie', 'serie.id', '=', 'folio.serie_id')
    ->select('folio')
    ->where('serie_id', '=', $serie)
    ->orderBy('folio.id','desc')
    ->get()->last();

   if($folio){
        $folio->increment('folio');
    }
```

---

Esto lo que hace es si va en el folio 1002 incrementa 1 ---> 1003

Pero tengo como parte de los requerimientos poder editar el folio manualmente, esto quiere decir que si el folio iba en 1002, el usuario puede ingresar 1024 (para esto ya tengo validaciones que indican que el folio ya existe), lo que hice al momento de mandar llamar el folio y para evitar que el folio iniciara en 1025 y se saltara los folios del 1003 al 1023, fue ordenar la consulta en forma descendente como se puede ver en el código que comparti.

Bien lo que intento hacer es validar que si existe el folio se incremente de nuevo y vuelva a comprobar, si el folio sigue existiendo se repita el proceso y siga aumentando el valor, ejemplo:

1002 (ya existe) --> entonces aumenta 1 ---> 1003 (resulta que tambien existe) ---> aumenta a 1004 etc... con esto claro que defino que se puede hacer con ciclo pero no tengo idea de como estructurarlo, hasta ahora tengo solo la consulta que verifica si existe el folio:

```
    $buscarFolio = folio::join('serie', 'serie.id', '=', 'folio.serie_id')
        ->select('folio')
        ->where('serie_id', '=', $serie)
        ->get();

        $existeFolio = count($buscarFolio);
if($existeFolio >=1){
  //  acción a ejecutar 
}
```

Al igual agradecería si me aportara alguna otra idea de como autoincrementar los folios con estas condiciones que manejo